# Ruby on Rails: Validating rendered HTML with MiniTest

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm going through the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) and I'm surprised that there is no mention of validating the HTML produced.

How does one validate HTML with Rails' MiniTest?

I'm after a local solution, not something which uses [W3C's Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) - this is too slow if I honour their request for maximum one hit per second.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 cool gems that can help you validating html:

- https://github.com/ericbeland/html_acceptance
- https://github.com/alexdunae/w3c_validators

Comment: AFAICT, `w3c_validators` does all the validating offline, making a separate POST request for each page to be validated - at a maximum of 1 per second at w3c's request. The offline solution doesn't really work for me - I'll update the question.

I've got an [issue](https://github.com/ericbeland/html_validation/issues/13#issuecomment-245624980) raised for `html_acceptance`, which I note hasn't really been updated for over a year. Did you try this one with MiniTest?